# javascript syntax terminology

Tags: javascript, syntax

-when we say

```
document.getElementById("someid").textContent;
```

is *"**textContent**"* an *instance* of the *method* **"getElementById()"** , or a *method* of the *object* "**document**"

Comment: Neither, `textContent` is a *property*. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: None of the two. It's a property of the anonymous object (which is an instance of `HTMLElement`) returned by the call to the method `getElementById` on the object `document`.

Comment: i'm still in the learning process of javascript .. didn't get to APIs and node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> document.getElmentById("someid").textContent;
> ```
>
> is "textContent" an instance of the method "getElementById()" , or a method of the object "document"

`textContent` is neither of these. "instance of a method" is not a thing. And it clearly is not a method of `document` because we didn't do `document.textContent`.

Let's break this into smaller pieces:

```
document
```

This is variable that refers to an object.

```
document.getElmentById("someid")
```

This is a function call where we pass a string `"someid"` as an argument and it returns a value.

```
document.getElmentById("someid").textContent;
```

This refers to the `textContent` property of the object that was returned by the function call. The value referred to here could be a simple value, such as a string, or it coudle be a more complex object. Just from the code, we cannot tell. To find out specifics, we can google `javascript getElementById` and find some documentation.

Another way to understand this better, try breaking the single line into multiple lines:

```
cosnt element = document.getElmentById("someid");
console.log(element);
console.log(element.textContent);
```